# How to correctly calculate label size with auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I know there is similar topics, but unfortunately their solution not work as i want. I have a label, with specific font, with constraints from left side equal to 16, and from right side equal to 16 also. So, for calculate expected text height i used this:

```
CGSize labelSize = [[strMod fineHtmlFromString:mdl.content] sizeWithFont:self.contentLabel.font
                                                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH - 32, (FLT_MAX))
                                                                   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        self.heightFullSizeLabel = labelSize.height;
```

32 is a number, that is easily calculated as 16+16 (constraints indent). SCREEN_WIDTH is defined as `#define SCREEN_WIDTH  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width`

Unfortunately, with that logic i get lesser height that i want to, so i had to increase 32 number to 40. Is there a way to precisely calculate label height dynamically with layout?

Comment: Why do you want to calculate it's height?

Comment: To calculate final height of main scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to know a text container size is to use `-sizeToFit` or `-sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size`.
The one you are using asks just the area occupied by a text, but it doesn't take into account padding or other view related stuff that can be applied.
You can see a huge difference in calculation if you use a UItexView that contains a lot of padding on each side

Comment: thanks, there would be nice if you correct my code snippet, would you be so kind?

Comment: Is not that difficult, just add the text to your label send sizeToFit or sizeThatFits, read the bounds of the label after that, and set  self.heightFullSizeLabel.

Comment: you mean i should only add [label sizeToFit]; after my declaration of it?

Comment: fist you need to pass the text, later sizeToFit

Comment: i tried to, but it gives me wrong height (20).[self.contentLabel sizeToFit];
        NSLog(@" height.. %f", self.contentLabel.frame.size.height);. I think this is because i want to calculate height before auto layout process complete

Comment: It can be, labels have a preferredWidth usually set to automatic, if the label is initially smaller of course the height will be different from the final state. Usually you shouldn't, but by setting preferredWidth to the final value should make the result correct, but the real solution should be manage that value "in sync" with auto layout

Answer (score 1):

Try this with your label font.

```
    CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FONT}
                                     context:nil];

    CGSize size = textRect.size;
    self.heightFullSizeLabel = size.height;
```